Why does Cloudflare block my Python request but allow Postman requests with the same headers?
I'm trying to make a request to a Cloudflare-protected endpoint using both Postman and Python's requests library. The request succeeds in Postman, but in Python, I get a 403 error. I've ensured that the headers (e.g., User-Agent, Accept, etc.) in my Python script match those in Postman, but the request is still blocked.
Why does Cloudflare block my Python request while allowing Postman requests? How can I fix this?
i can achieve below output using selenium or headless selenium but i want to know why can i not do this using requests, while it can be done in postman.
when i run in postman it give result like this
{
    "schemaVersion": "1.0.0",
    "cg": null,
    "gp": null,
    "ts": null,
    "cmc": null,
    "ti": {
        "id": "R4zj9VDraGU9JFViH7mojY",
        "chain": {
            "id": "solana"
        },
        "address": "5aBbK8HPtwH9DvXnSTXbakRW34ateooZK1bnb7qhegeZ",
        "name": "Dino Game",
        "symbol": "DINO",
        "description": "$DINO is a one-of-a-kind GameFi meme coin that brings the nostalgia of the classic Dino Game to life while offering real-world rewards. It’s where fun meets utility, creating a revolutionary experience in the meme coin space.",

}}
the below code is generated using postman
import requests

url = "https://io.dexscreener.com/dex/pair-details/v3/solana/HKj2acbuMto92TvjtBfpPyG2im28og5b647gh1K62CAm"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:133.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/133.0',
  'Cookie': '__cf_bm=Pa25nvnzsUCW1AnI5oCV6ZDLXV8HY.VjsZM1squ8D30-1735078602-1.0.1.1-7WIFetntuMUCOgKEH0XlF8uKq8e4t5sS403X8XEwzkrACUTs1woAlaXzzmN65nZksyujfMGKiD_HqyD9MRED6mASCQxtAbySJGLSyGVVvII; __cflb=04dTof7UnGZLJbSktrXU5s6TEcm2ZGkWquifmfRNx5'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)


i copied url requests from chrome and paste in postman, it did not work.
i copied url requests from firefox and paste in postman, it worked.


what i noticed ?


firefox

open inspection mode
copy and paste this url "https://io.dexscreener.com/dex/pair-details/v3/solana/HKj2acbuMto92TvjtBfpPyG2im28og5b647gh1K62CAm"
open this url in firefox --> copy value -->> copy as Curl(windows)
open postman and paste this data and run, we recieve response with status code 200

chrome

do above same process but recived 403 error.
to get 200 code, i untick all keys like (accept, dnt, priority, connection, accept-encoding etc...)
if we copy user-agent from firefox data and paste it in chrome it not worked unless we changed key name from user-agent to User-Agent (hear i am talking about small character to upper character)
we need only 2 value in last to recieve 200 code in postman.

after that i generated this below code using postman. but it is not working in script.
import requests

url = "https://io.dexscreener.com/dex/pair-details/v3/solana/HKj2acbuMto92TvjtBfpPyG2im28og5b647gh1K62CAm"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:133.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/133.0',
  'Cookie': 'cookie data'} ## (i changed cookie data here, we can get cookie using above mentioned mmethod)

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)


Get the session keys into Wireshark and compare side-by-side. Cloudflare has a team of people looking for ways clients differ to better detect when one client is pretending to be another -- it could be something like capitalization of headers (which some libraries normalize and others don't) giving you away, or ordering of those headers, or a difference in which TLS library is in use (if your user agent says Windows but requests is using a TLS library that doesn't exist there), or who-knows-what. You need to compare the traffic in a protocol analyzer to have a place to start.

I tried to use Scrapy for this task and in Scrapy I am receiving status code 200.
In Scrapy I used the above headers and it worked.

i want to know that why scrapy can accsess page but requests can not ?

Right, so use a protocol analyzer to compare the traffic.

when i used wireshark, i see QUIC as a protocol

In which? Both scrapy and requests, or only one, or only the other? And if you dig deeper into the request, what else is there? (You might need to extract session keys to allow decryption -- that's what I was talking about earlier).
